# Why "copy" is not being invoked?

Tags: objective-c

I have the following object:

```
@interface SomeObject : NSObject
{
    NSString *title;
}

@property (copy) NSString *title;

@end
```

And I have another object:

```
    @interface AnotherObject : NSObject{
        NSString *title;
    }

    @property (copy) NSString *title;

    - (AnotherObject*)init;
    - (void)dealloc;
    - (void) initWithSomeObject: (SomeObject*) pSomeObject;
    + (AnotherObject*) AnotherObjectWithSomeObject (SomeObject*) pSomeObject;

    @end

@implementation AnotherObject
@synthesize title


    - (AnotherObject*)init {
        if (self = [super init]) {
            title = nil;
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)dealloc {
        if (title) [title release];
        [super dealloc];
    }

    -(void) initWithSomeObject: (SomeObject*) pSomeObject
    {
        title = [pSomeObject title]; //Here copy is not being invoked, have to use [ [pSomeObject title] copy]
    }


    + (AnotherObject*) AnotherObjectWithSomeObject (SomeObject*) pSomeObject;
    {
        [pSomeObject retain];
        AnotherObject *tempAnotherObject = [ [AnotherObject alloc] init];
        [tempAnotherObject initWithSomeObject: pSomeObject];
        [pSomeObject release];
        return tempAnotherObject;
    }

@end
```

I do not understand, why copy is not being invoked when I am assigning "title = [pSomeObject title]". I always thought if i set "copy" in property it is always going to be invoked. I have a error in my code or I don't understand something?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a setter to get called you need to use the *dot* notation.

```
self.title = [pSomeObject title];
```

or...to use the *dot* notation for pSomeObject too

```
self.title = pSomeObject.title;
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the difference.